# Find a group G such that its derived series is a subnormal series but not a normal series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find a group G such that its derived series is a subnormal series but not a normal series. I have tried several groups G and still can't find a group G with this property. Is anyone know such an example?

Comment: All memebers of the derived series are characteristic in $G$, so there is no such example.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is a solvable group, then the derived series of $G$ is also a normal series of $G$. This follows from the fact that $G^{(n)}$ for any positive integer $n$ is always a normal subgroup of $G$. If $G$ is not solvable, then the derived subgroup does not terminate in the trivial subgroup. In some sense, we can say that, if $G$ is not solvable, then the derived subgroup is neither a subnormal series nor a normal series.

So the answer to your question is "there is no such group".